# Conceptual explanation of Optical Tweezers

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, experimental-physics, geometric-optics

I have been trying to get my head around Optical Tweezers and why they work.

I understand it as that light rays holds the particle in place since if the particle moves, it changes the profile of the light an hence its momentum. Because of the conservation of momentum a resorting force would be exerted on the particle. That is, it is the geometry of the rays that lies behind the restoring force.

However, according to the Wikipedia article it can also be explained as the light acting as a non-homogeneous electric field. Particles that become dipoles under varying electric fields are held into place by the electric force.

I am not sure how to consolidate these two different explanations.
**To what extent does it matter if the particle under study is dielectric?**

[image]

> Dielectric objects are attracted to the center of the beam, slightly
>   above the beam waist, as described in the text. The force applied on
>   the object depends linearly on its displacement from the trap center
>   just as with a simple spring system. Note that in contrast to what is
>   shown in the figure, the force is equal to $$-k_{trap} x$$ (Wikipedia).